# Can I use Django's Generic Views with google-app-engine-django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-generic-views

Put simply, is there a way to get generic views to work?

If I try the following in urls.py:

```
publisher_info = {
    'queryset': Publisher.objects.all(),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^publishers/$', list_detail.object_list, publisher_info)
)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError at /publishers 'Query'
>
> object has no attribute '_clone'

Is this due to the fact that Django models aren't supported on App Engine and google-app-engine-django hasn't been able to port over all associated code? If so, would it be easy to fix myself?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this project should provide that functionality as a core feature.

http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/

Comment: Thanks, but while I'm aware of app-engine-patch I'm specifically asking about [google-app-engine-django][1]. It looks like it is [not possible][2].


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/
  [2]: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=43

Comment: Yeah. It is unfortunate that app engine and django don't play more nicely together.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be No.